# Generate random public url

Tags: zend-framework, url, doctrine

I'm development a survey system where a teacher can login onto the system and then create his own survey.

When he (the teacher) finishes the survey, I need to generate a public url for his survey, then he can give that url to his students and then they can answer that survey, but, students don't need sign up on my sistem to do that.

So, how can I generate public random URL to enable this behavior?
I use Zend Framework 1.11 for server side, Doctrine ORM 1.2.4 for Database and jQuery for client side.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What did you mean by a random url?

Comment: For example: when the teacher active the survey, I want to generate an URL like http://example.com/LKIO21289sKLQPO, then teacher give the URL to his students and they complete the survey when access to that URL

Comment: If you're storing the survey info in a database, which I'm assuming you are, why not just assign each row (each survey) an id and use `$_GET["id"]`? For example something like `http://example.com/survey.php?id=123` will load the survey with id of `123`. I don't really see the benefit of generating a random URL.

Comment: The idea of use random URL is that students couldn't find surveys that are not addressed to them. Only they can answer surveys from their teacher, not from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular Zend controller and action combination to perform that task. You can save the survey in database table with a random key (may be the hash value of concatenation between the time stamp and survey name). Then send a link which contains the hash value and once the random value is received back to the controller it can be used to extract and display the matching survey from the database. If you do not check (exclude) the authentication for requests for that particular controller and action it can be accessed by public users.